# What are the backticks in Apollo type definitions?

Tags: apollo

For instance the two ` here:

```
const typeDefinition = [`
  schema {
    query: RootQuery
  }

  type RootQuery {
    aNumber: Int
  }
`];
```

http://docs.apollostack.com/apollo-server/generate-schema.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a template string, which is a thing in ES2015: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0):

Backticks are commonly used to designate multi-line strings. ES6, GraphQL and Apollo use backticks to support multi-line strings and [interpolation](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/pull/266/files).